# Unexpected behaviour of rootDir and outDir

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am trying to use TypeScript with React Native.

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "es2015",
        "jsx": "react",
        "outDir": "build",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "typings/index.d.ts",
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.tsx"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "index.android.js",
        "index.ios.js",
        "build",
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": false
}
```

I would like all .ts(x) files in the src directory to be compiled to the build directory.

**Expected:**

```
MyAwesomeReactNativeApp/
├── src/
│   └── index.tsx
└── build/
    └── index.js
```

**Got:**

```
MyAwesomeReactNativeApp/
├── src/
│   └── index.tsx
└── build/
    ├── src/
    │   └── index.js
    ├── index.android.js
    ├── index.ios.js
    └── __tests__/
```

The compiler complains:

```
error TS6059: File '[...]/__tests__/index.android.js' is not under 'rootDir' '[...]/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
error TS6059: File '[...]/__tests__/index.ios.js' is not under 'rootDir' '[...]/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
error TS6059: File '[...]/index.android.js' is not under 'rootDir' '[...]/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
error TS6059: File '[...]/index.ios.js' is not under 'rootDir' '[...]/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are the `[...]`s different (specifically having different case)? I'm seeing something similar on my Mach where the error is `error TS6059: File '/Users/[...]' is not under 'rootDir' '/users/[...]'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.`. One is `/Users` and the other is `/users`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled across the same problem. I think it happens when you initialise a project with react-native-cli and test the project with react-native run-ios/run-android. And then start converting the project to a react-native typescript project afterwards. That creates 'normal' react-native build artifacts and typescript build artifacts later on.

For me it helped to put __tests__ into the excludes in tsconfig.json.

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es2015",
    "jsx": "react",
    "outDir": "build",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true
},
"filesGlob": [
    "typings/index.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx"
],
"exclude":[
    "index.android.js",
    "index.ios.js",
    "build",
    "node_modules",
    "__tests__"
],
"compileOnSave": false
```

}

Comment: Awesome, `exclude` works well! 

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error message regarding files not being "under rootDir". In my case it was for a web project rather than React Native, but the solution may be along the same lines.

The problem is that I was using a single ts-loader rule to load from *multiple paths containing a tsconfig.json file* (eg. `node_modules/moduleA/src/.*\.ts`,  `node_modules/moduleB/src/.*\.ts`); thus, ts-loader would "find the project tsconfig.json" inside one of those node-module folders, and then complain that the other node-modules' files were not within its `rootDir` path.

The solution: Use a separate ts-loader rule+instance for each node-module folder.

Example: https://github.com/Venryx/vwebapp-framework/blob/8879154136e28800158e581f146bbb382092d7d3/Scripts/Build/WebpackConfig.ts#L291

That's it! Problem solved in my project, without modifying any of the packages' `tsconfig.json` files or the like.

P.S. Some additional background on this subject: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/647